# Missing sourcemaps in Typescript + Webpack project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, source-maps

I've created a Github repo that has all the [source code](https://github.com/fay-jai/tsc-react-webpack) related to this question. I'm able to load `build/index.html` in the browser after running `npm install`. However, when I view the sources tab in Chrome, I don't see the source maps associated with the `.tsx` files.

Here's a screenshot of what I see: [image: no-source-map]

I've added `sourceMap: true` in my tsconfig.json as well as `debug: true` and `devtool: "source-map"` in my webpack.config.json. Any thoughts on what I'm missing here?

**EDIT:**

**This might be a silly question, but do you have to use `webpack-dev-server` in order to see the sourcemaps?**

Comment: I don't see a problem here, I cloned your repo: `npm install && typings install && npm run dev` -> opened chrome -> F12 -> navigate to localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server  (or localhost:8080/build - both works) and I'm seeing a log from `ReactDOM.js:66` and `app.tsx:14`, so sourceMaps seem to be working - maybe your issue is to FIRST open the dev-tools before entering the url (or hit F5 after opening the dev-tools) - but your config seems to work. - Running Node v4.2.6  (>=4.x.x is required for Webpack i think)

Comment: @olsn when I initially posed this question, I was wondering if I could see the source maps when I'm just using webpack and not webpack-dev-server. Seems like in order to see source maps, I'll need to use webpack-dev-server, right?

Comment: no, the source-maps will be generated with both `webpack` as well as `webpack-dev-server` - since it is basically the same thing, with the addition of the `dev-server` automatically serving the stuff that `webpack` packaged. - So you can use `npm run build` or `npm run dev` and both will generate a source-map.

Comment: @olsn unfortunately, that's not the case for me when i'm using `webpack` and not `webpack-dev-server` :(

Comment: You used ’npm run build’? Make sure there is no global version of webpack installed. Are there any errors or warnings in the log? I tested it again before my last comment and it works. What system? What node version? Where are you looking for the map? (Its generated into ’build/bundle.js.map’ you might want to clear the build folder before.

Answer (score 4):

Your `tsconfig.json` might be well.

Try in your `webpack.config.js` either `devtool: "inline-source-map"` or remove the two options od `debug` and `devtool` complete.
In my case I don't need them.

Comment: Hm I tried both of your suggestions and neither solve it for me :(

Answer (score 1):

I had to add a filepath for the sourcemap file. Take a look at the output part of this webpack.config.js:
https://github.com/nwinger/reactreduxtodo/blob/master/webpack.config.js

Comment: Out of curiosity, were you able to see sourcemaps after running webpack or webpack-dev-server?

Comment: Yes, the sourcemaps were available in chrome dev. console :)